# Equation of the parabola which touches $x$ axis at $(a,0)$ and $y$ axis at $(0,b)$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Prove that the equation of parabola which touches $x$ axis at $(a,0)$ and $y$ axis at $(0,b)$ is $$\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{b}}=1.$$

Comment: What's a "parabola", in your definition?

Comment: Have you done any work of your own on this?

Comment: yes i proved that it is a parabola from general equation of second degree in x and y.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.